# jquery datatable to display data in uppercase

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery datatable is displaying existing rows from the database .
I want to display the entire data in Upper case where some of the data in database are in lower . I already defind columns and data for the datatable. how could I convert the data to upper case either at the time of rendering or at the time when fetching from database.

Any body please give me suggestion on converting the jQuery data table data to upper case

Thanks in Advance
Subin

Comment: Add your code to your question and tell us what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using css.. 
Just do

```
#myDatatableId {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `css` to `td` to make all text in upper case

```
<style>
td {
     text-transform:uppercase
}
    </style>
```

If you want to be more specific you can target the td of specific table only by `id` or `class selector`